# solaris 10 keymap fn and windows keys

Tags: keyboard, solaris

I have a sparc64 T5220 and I would like to modify my keymap because when I connect with ssh to the sverver/zones from my laptop with FN and Windows Keys.  When I use those keys I got garbage and not the right result: FN+left_arrow = goto the beginning of line (console/shell), FN+right_arrow = goto end of line, etc.

Thx for your help

Yves

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). Its really good as an ssh client and allows a lot of customization.

Comment: Dear, no but I use UNIX/Linux on my laptop